# Why when movex is defined after assignment does python 3.5 return UnboundLocalError: local variable 'movex' was referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.5

So I'm following a pdf on game development with Python and pygame and I'm making a puzzle where blocks in the pygame window move randomly to generate a puzzle it runs up until it moves a puzzle piece down or up which confuses me cause the error is about movex being referenced before assignment when it has been assigned before it was referenced I'm new to Python but not new to programming just for the life of me I can't work out the issue I've tried tabifying my code and untabifying my code my problem is I'm getting this error when running the code,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/Documents/Slidingpuzzle.py", line 320, in <module>
main()
 File "/home/pi/Documents/Slidingpuzzle.py", line 51, in main
mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80)
 File "/home/pi/Documents/Slidingpuzzle.py", line 294, in 
 generateNewPuzzle
slideAnimation(board, move, 'Generating new puzzle...', animationSpeed=int(TILESIZE / 3))
File "/home/pi/Documents/Slidingpuzzle.py", line 263, in slideAnimation
moveLeft, moveTop = getLeftTopOfTile(movex, movey)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'movex' referenced before assignment
```

I have defined movex before using it, the desired behaviour would be for the game to function correctly, not to crash when attempting to move a piece up or down. here's my code

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

#Constrantes
BOARDWIDTH = 4
BOARDHEIGHT = 4
TILESIZE = 80
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30
BLANK = None

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BRIGHTBLUE = (0, 50, 255)
DARKTURQUOISE = (3, 54, 73)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

BGCOLOR = DARKTURQUOISE
TILECOLOR = GREEN
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE
BORDERCOLOR = BRIGHTBLUE
BASICFONTSIZE = 20

BUTTONCOLOR = WHITE
BUTTONTEXTCOLOR = BLACK
MESSAGECOLOR = WHITE

XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (TILESIZE * BOARDWIDTH + (BOARDWIDTH - 1))) / 2)
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (TILESIZE * BOARDHEIGHT + (BOARDHEIGHT - 1))) / 2)

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT, NEW_SURF
    global NEW_RECT, SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Slide Puzzle')
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', BASICFONTSIZE)

    # Store the option buttons and their rectangles in OPTIONS.
    RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT = makeText('Reset',    TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 90)
    NEW_SURF,   NEW_RECT   = makeText('New Game', TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 60)
    SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT = makeText('Solve',    TEXTCOLOR, TILECOLOR, WINDOWWIDTH - 120, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)

    mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80)
    SOLVEDBOARD = getStartingBoard() # a solved board is the same as the board in a start state.
    allMoves = [] # list of moves made from the solved configuration

    while True: # main game loop
        slideTo = None # the direction, if any, a tile should slide
        msg = 'Click tile or press arrow keys to slide.' # contains the message to show in the upper left corner.
        if mainBoard == SOLVEDBOARD:
            msg = 'Solved!'

        drawBoard(mainBoard, msg)

        checkForQuit()
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                spotx, spoty = getSpotClicked(mainBoard, event.pos[0], event.pos[1])

                if (spotx, spoty) == (None, None):
                    # check if the user clicked on an option button
                    if RESET_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        resetAnimation(mainBoard, allMoves) # clicked on Reset button
                        allMoves = []
                    elif NEW_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        mainBoard, solutionSeq = generateNewPuzzle(80) # clicked on New Game button
                        allMoves = []
                    elif SOLVE_RECT.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        resetAnimation(mainBoard, solutionSeq + allMoves) # clicked on Solve button
                        allMoves = []
                else:
                    # check if the clicked tile was next to the blank spot

                    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(mainBoard)
                    if spotx == blankx + 1 and spoty == blanky:
                        slideTo = LEFT
                    elif spotx == blankx - 1 and spoty == blanky:
                        slideTo = RIGHT
                    elif spotx == blankx and spoty == blanky + 1:
                        slideTo = UP
                    elif spotx == blankx and spoty == blanky - 1:
                        slideTo = DOWN

            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                # check if the user pressed a key to slide a tile
                if event.key in (K_LEFT, K_a) and isValidMove(mainBoard, LEFT):
                    slideTo = LEFT
                elif event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_d) and isValidMove(mainBoard, RIGHT):
                    slideTo = RIGHT
                elif event.key in (K_UP, K_w) and isValidMove(mainBoard, UP):
                    slideTo = UP
                elif event.key in (K_DOWN, K_s) and isValidMove(mainBoard, DOWN):
                    slideTo = DOWN

        if slideTo:
            slideAnimation(mainBoard, slideTo, 'Click tile or press arrow keys to slide.', 8) # show slide on screen
            makeMove(mainBoard, slideTo)
            allMoves.append(slideTo) # record the slide
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def checkForQuit():
    for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT):
        terminate()
    for event in pygame.event.get(KEYUP):
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        pygame.event.post(event)


def getStartingBoard():
        # Return a board data structure with tiles in the solved state.
        # For example, if BOARDWIDTH and BOARDHEIGHT are both 3, this function      
        # returns [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, BLANK]]
    counter = 1
    board = []
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        column = []
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            column.append(counter)
            counter += BOARDWIDTH
        board.append(column)
        counter -= BOARDWIDTH * (BOARDHEIGHT - 1) + BOARDWIDTH - 1

    board[BOARDWIDTH-1][BOARDHEIGHT-1] = BLANK
    return board


def getBlankPosition(board):
        # Return the x and y of board coordinates of the blank space.
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            if board[x][y] == BLANK:
                return (x, y)


def makeMove(board, move):
    # This function does not check is the move is valid
    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)

    if move == UP:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx][blanky + 1] = board[blankx][blanky + 1], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == DOWN:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx][blanky - 1] = board[blankx][blanky - 1], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == LEFT:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx + 1][blanky] = board[blankx + 1][blanky], board[blankx][blanky]
    elif move == RIGHT:
        board[blankx][blanky], board[blankx - 1][blanky] = board[blankx - 1][blanky], board[blankx][blanky]


def isValidMove(board, move):
    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)
    return (move == UP and blanky != len(board[0]) - 1) or \
           (move == DOWN and blanky != 0) or \
           (move == LEFT and blankx != len(board) - 1) or \
           (move == RIGHT and blankx != 0)


def getRandomMove(board, lastMove=None):
    validMoves = [UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT]

    if lastMove == UP or not isValidMove(board, DOWN):
        validMoves.remove(DOWN)
    if lastMove == DOWN or not isValidMove(board, UP):
        validMoves.remove(UP)
    if lastMove == LEFT or not isValidMove(board, RIGHT):
        validMoves.remove(RIGHT)
    if lastMove == RIGHT or not isValidMove(board, LEFT):
        validMoves.remove(LEFT)

        return random.choice(validMoves)


def getLeftTopOfTile(tileX, tileY):
    left = XMARGIN + (tileX * TILESIZE) + (tileX - 1)
    top = YMARGIN + (tileY * TILESIZE) + (tileY - 1)
    return (left, top)


def getSpotClicked(board, x, y):
    for tileX in range(len(board)):
        for tileY in range(len(board[0])):
            left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(tileX, tileY)
            tileRect = pygame.Rect(left, top, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
            if tileRect.collidepoint(x, y):
                return (tileX, tileY)
    return (None, None)


def drawTile(tilex, tiley, number, adjx=0, adjy=0):
    left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(tilex, tiley)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, TILECOLOR, (left + adjx, top + adjy, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
    textSurf = BASICFONT.render(str(number), True, TEXTCOLOR)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.center = left + int(TILESIZE / 2) + adjx, top + int(TILESIZE / 2) + adjy
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf, textRect)



def makeText(text, color, bgcolor, top, left):
    textSurf = BASICFONT.render(text, True, color, bgcolor)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.topleft = (top, left)
    return (textSurf, textRect)


def drawBoard(board, message):
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        if message:
            textSurf, textRect = makeText(message, MESSAGECOLOR, BGCOLOR, 5, 5)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf, textRect)

        for tilex in range(len(board)):
            for tiley in range(len(board[0])):
                if board[tilex][tiley]:
                    drawTile(tilex, tiley, board[tilex][tiley])

        left, top = getLeftTopOfTile(0, 0)
        width = BOARDWIDTH * TILESIZE
        height = BOARDHEIGHT * TILESIZE
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BORDERCOLOR, (left - 5, top - 5, width + 11, height + 11), 4)

        DISPLAYSURF.blit(RESET_SURF, RESET_RECT)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT)


def slideAnimation(board, direction, message, animationSpeed):
    # Note: This function does not check if the move is valid.

    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)
    if direction == UP:
        movex = blankx
        movey = blanky + 1
    elif direction == DOWN:
        movex = blankx
        movey = blanky - 1
    elif direction == LEFT:
        movex = blankx + 1
        movey = blanky
    elif direction == RIGHT:
        movex = blankx - 1
        movey = blanky

    # prepare the base surface
    drawBoard(board, message)
    baseSurf = DISPLAYSURF.copy()
    # draw a blank space over the moving tile on the baseSurf Surface.
    moveLeft, moveTop = getLeftTopOfTile(movex, movey)
    pygame.draw.rect(baseSurf, BGCOLOR, (moveLeft, moveTop, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    for i in range(0, TILESIZE, animationSpeed):
        # animate the tile sliding over
        checkForQuit()
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(baseSurf, (0, 0))
        if direction == UP:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], 0, -i)
        if direction == DOWN:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], 0, i)
        if direction == LEFT:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], -i, 0)
        if direction == RIGHT:
            drawTile(movex, movey, board[movex][movey], i, 0)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)


def generateNewPuzzle(numSlides):
    # From a starting configuration, make numSlides number of moves (and
    # animate these moves).
    sequence = []
    board = getStartingBoard()
    drawBoard(board, '')
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(500) # pause 500 milliseconds for effect
    lastMove = None
    for i in range(numSlides):
        move = getRandomMove(board, lastMove)
        slideAnimation(board, move, 'Generating new puzzle...', animationSpeed=int(TILESIZE / 3))
        makeMove(board, move)
        sequence.append(move)
        lastMove = move
    return (board, sequence)


def resetAnimation(board, allMoves):
    # make all of the moves in allMoves in reverse.
    revAllMoves = allMoves[:] # gets a copy of the list
    revAllMoves.reverse()

    for move in revAllMoves:
        if move == UP:
            oppositeMove = DOWN
        elif move == DOWN:
            oppositeMove = UP
        elif move == RIGHT:
            oppositeMove = LEFT
        elif move == LEFT:
            oppositeMove = RIGHT
        slideAnimation(board, oppositeMove, '', animationSpeed=int(TILESIZE / 2))
        makeMove(board, oppositeMove)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. You're using the `movex` variable before actually assigning it to something.

Comment: def slideAnimation(board, direction, message, animationSpeed):
    # Note: This function does not check if the move is valid.

    blankx, blanky = getBlankPosition(board)
    if direction == UP:
        movex = blankx
        movey = blanky + 1
    elif direction == DOWN:
        movex = blankx
        movey = blanky - 1
    elif direction == LEFT:
        movex = blankx + 1
        movey = blanky
    elif direction == RIGHT:
        movex = blankx - 1
        movey = blanky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an indentation error in `getRandomMove`.

The return statement needs to be un-indented one level. It's hard to tell for sure though because the indentation in the question is messed up. This worked for me though.